# Passing command object from SimpleFormController to a Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where I need to pass a command object in Spring MVC from SimpleFormController to a Controller (Its a controller that implements the Controller Interface). The version of Spring is 2.5 and the configuration is XML based.

From the SimpleFormController a redirect is being made to the Controller. However, the call to ${command.myVal} returns null even though I have added session="true" in the jsp that the controller points to.

The Redirect Code in SimpleFormController is :

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/SimpleController.do");
```

For the SimpleFormController, the sessionForm property is set to true in spring.xml

```
<property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
```

To solve this, I had to explicitly add the command object in the SimpleFormController to the HttpSession :

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
 session.setAttribute("command", commandObj);
```

And in the Simplecontroller, I had to create a Map of String to Obj and pass that to the View. Here again, I took the commandObj from the Session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
resultMap.put("command", session.getAttribute("command"));
```

Please suggest if there is a better way without using Annotations. This somehow seems a long-winded way of getting the result.

Comment: Please show us the redirect code.

Comment: Is the command object stored in session? If not, its state is not going to survive the redirect.

Comment: SessionForm is true for the SimpleFormController                 <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>

Answer (score 0):

In order for Spring to parse the command object, you need to submit the form directly to a controller which extends BaseCommandController.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html

If your SimpleFormController itself received the form submission, then you could store the command in the session, for use by the Controller.

(and ofcourse this would all become easier if you harnessed the annotation-based approach to Spring MVC)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks amir, I found a way to do this using session, but would be great to know if that was NOT the Spring way.

Comment: It's no more deprecated than SimpleFormController! Both were deprecated in v3.0 in favour of annotated controllers (i.e. using special annotations on plain Java classes, instead of implementing/extending Spring's Controller interface+class heirarchy). Look them up, they're much nicer to use for this kind of stuff, and available since 2.5. You could even say that SimpleFormController itself is no longer the 'Spring way'

Comment: Didn't intend to cause a flame. The reason I posted on BaseCommandController was because when I used it in code, I saw the deprecation, which was however missing for SimpleFormController. On using annotations, this is a project where the XML way is being used and its preferred to keep it that way unless there is some feature absolutely unachievable without annotations.

Comment: No worries - did you try configuring your SimpleFormController with setSessionForm(true) ? It might save you needing to store it in the session explicitly. Just a thought ...